# Mail not sent using PhpMailer

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I have to send multiple mails using PhpMailer. Below is my code:

```
<?php
include 'class.phpmailer.php';
$friendsarr=array('test1@gmail.com','test2@example.com');
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->From = 'test3@test.com';
$mail->FromName = 'CK';
$mail->Subject = 'FW:'.'Test';
$mail->AltBody = '';
$i=0;
foreach ($friendsarr as $value) {
    $mail2 = clone $mail;
    $friendmail=$value;
    $message='<table border="0" align="left" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                  <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td height="28">
                                <div>
                                    <div align="right"><a href="http://integrationyantra.com/en/?join=1" style=""><strong>Subscribe Me!</strong></a></div>
                                    <div align="left">Dear Recipient,<br/>CK has forwarded this email to you with the following message: test</div><br/><div><strong>Please Note: </strong>You have <strong>NOT</strong> been added to any email lists. If you no longer wish to recieve these messages, please contact <a href="#">test4@test.com</a>.</div>
                                    <br/><div align="left">test here'.$i.'</div>
                                </div>
                            </td> 
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
               </table>';
    $mail2->MsgHTML($message);
    $mail2->AddAddress($value, 'Recipient');
    $sent=$mail2->Send();
    echo $sent.' '.$value.'<br/>';
    $mail2->ClearAddresses();
    $i++;
}
?>
```

The value `$sent` shows `1`, but mails are not sent to any of the mail addresses. There are no errors too. Can anyone tell me what is missing?

Comment: may be its server problem because few servers won't accept this kind of mail functions..you should try to send the email using SMTP Authentication..check this link http://email.about.com/od/emailprogrammingtips/qt/PHP_Email_SMTP_Authentication.htm

Comment: Errors might appear in the syslog, mail.log, php error log or webservers error log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like an environment problem, but I've fixed several problems in your code anyway - There's no need to clone the PHPMailer instance inside the loop!

By default it's using the PHP mail() function to send messages, so it will be submitting to localhost via your sendmail binary. When using that route you can't get much in the way of debug info - you can get much more (though it's slower) by using SMTP instead - just change the call to `IsMail()` to `IsSMTP()` and you'll get lots of debug output. To test sending via mail() you can set your sendmail path in php.ini to point at the `fakesendmail.sh` script in PHPMailer's test folder and it will simply pipe your messages into a temp folder.

Beyond that, you should check your mail server logs (often `/var/log/mail.log`).

```
<?php
require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';
$friendsarr=array('test1@gmail.com','test2@example.com');
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;
$mail->isMail();
$mail->Host = 'localhost';
$mail->Port = 25;
$mail->From = 'test3@test.com';
$mail->FromName = 'CK';
$mail->Subject = 'FW:'.'Test';
$mail->AltBody = '';
$i=0;
foreach ($friendsarr as $value) {
    $message='<table border="0" align="left" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                  <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td height="28">
                                <div>
                                    <div align="right"><a href="http://integrationyantra.com/en/?join=1" style=""><strong>Subscribe Me!</strong></a></div>
                                    <div align="left">Dear Recipient,<br/>CK has forwarded this email to you with the following message: test</div><br/><div><strong>Please Note: </strong>You have <strong>NOT</strong> been added to any email lists. If you no longer wish to recieve these messages, please contact <a href="#">test4@test.com</a>.</div>
                                    <br/><div align="left">test here'.$i.'</div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
               </table>';
    $mail->MsgHTML($message);
    $mail->AddAddress($value, 'Recipient');
    $sent=$mail->Send();
    echo $sent.' '.$value.'<br/>';
    $mail->ClearAddresses();
    $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this function

We have created a function think so it will work

```
/* send_mail
 * function definition to send mail by phpmailer function
 * @param $to, $body, $subject, $fromaddress, $fromname
 * @return boolean true/false
 */
require(DOC_ROOT."/class.phpmailer.php");

function send_mail($to, $body, $subject, $fromaddress='', $fromname=''){

    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->IsSMTP();        // set mailer to use SMTP
    $mail->WordWrap = 50;       // set word wrap to 50 characters
    $mail->IsHTML(true);        // set email format to HTML

    if($fromname!='') {
        $mail->FromName = $fromname;
    } else {
        $mail->FromName = "Site Name";
    }

    if($fromaddress!='') {
        $mail->From = $fromaddress;
    } else {
        $mail->From = "info@test.com";
    }

    $mail->AddAddress($to); // set receiver email from here

    $mail->Subject = $subject;
    $mail->Body    = $body;
    $mail->AltBody = strip_tags($body);

    if(!$mail->Send())
    {
       //echo "Message could not be sent. <p>";
       //echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
       return false;
    } else {
        //print_r($mail);
        //echo "Message has been sent";
        return true;
    }
}

@send_mail($to, $body, $subject, $from, $fromname);
```

Comment: Doesn't explain why the OP's code doesn't work. Error supression should not be used btw.

Comment: We have used the same function in our project it is getting sent

Comment: the from address is the $mail->From = 'test3@test.com'; change this to valis server think so it will work

Comment: That's a good point, which your answer does not cover unfortunately ;)

Comment: you need to make sure that your from address is a valid email account setup on that server

Comment: The code is not working for gmail,yahoo and hotmail email addresses. But its working for microsoft outlook!